# Trying To Deserialize JSON Dictionairy Using Objects

Tags: json, vb.net, json.net

As standard, I've created a web request and receive a response as JSON format. I'm trying to deserialize this JSON using JSON.NET (I don't think I need this though).

I've tried using the following code, however I'm not entirely sure on how to make the object actually contain some data. When I run this code, I get an error message displaying that my JObject "current" is "Nothing".

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.IO
Imports Newtonsoft.Json.Linq
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
  ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = True
  ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = CType(3072, SecurityProtocolType)
  ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 9999
  Dim uriString As String = "https://dev.tescolabs.com/grocery/products/?query=chicken&offset=0&limit=2"
  Dim uri As New Uri(uriString)

  Dim r As HttpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(uri)
  r.Headers("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key") = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  r.Method = "GET"
  r.Proxy = Nothing
  Dim re As HttpWebResponse = r.GetResponse()

  Dim read As New StreamReader(re.GetResponseStream())
  Dim raw As String = read.ReadToEnd()
  Dim a As JObject = JObject.Parse(raw)
  Dim current As JObject = DirectCast(a("image"), JObject)
  MessageBox.Show(current("image"))
End Sub
End Class
Public Class Totals
  Public Property all As Integer
  Public Property _new As Integer
  Public Property offer As Integer
End Class

Public Class Result
  Public Property image As String
  Public Property superDepartment As String
  Public Property tpnb As Integer
  Public Property ContentsMeasureType As String
  Public Property name As String
  Public Property UnitOfSale As Integer
  Public Property description() As String
  Public Property AverageSellingUnitWeight As Single
  Public Property UnitQuantity As String
  Public Property id As Integer
  Public Property ContentsQuantity As Single
  Public Property department As String
  Public Property price As Single
  Public Property unitprice As Single
End Class
```

So, in textbox1, should be each product, including all of the information for each product. After extracting all of this information, I would ultimately like to add the information for each product in a datagridview, to present the information in a more clear manner. However, I can't get past this stage.

I have now tried the following code:

```
Dim results = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Result)(raw) 
    For Each image In results.image
        TextBox1.Text = "Image URL:" + results.image
    Next
```

JSON I receive as response:

```
{
  "uk" : {
    "ghs" : {
      "products" : {
        "input_query" : "chicken",
        "output_query" : "chicken",
        "filters" : { },
        "queryPhase" : "primary",
        "totals" : {
          "all" : 1358,
          "new" : 9,
          "offer" : 478
        },
        "config" : "default",
        "results" : [ {
          "image" : "http://img.tesco.com/Groceries/pi/325/5057008546325/IDShot_90x90.jpg",
          "superDepartment" : "Fresh Food",
          "tpnb" : 81866107,
          "ContentsMeasureType" : "G",
          "name" : "Tesco British Chicken Breast Portions 650G",
          "UnitOfSale" : 1,
          "description" : [ "Fresh class A skinless chicken breast fillet portions."],
          "AverageSellingUnitWeight" : 0.746,
          "UnitQuantity" : "KG",
          "id" : 294007923,
          "ContentsQuantity" : 650,
          "department" : "Fresh Meat & Poultry",
          "price" : 3.8,
          "unitprice" : 5.85
        }, {
          "image" : "http://img.tesco.com/Groceries/pi/531/5054775703531/IDShot_90x90.jpg",
          "superDepartment" : "Fresh Food",
          "tpnb" : 64083120,
          "ContentsMeasureType" : "KG",
          "name" : "Tesco British Large Whole Chicken 1.55-1.95Kg",
          "UnitOfSale" : 1,
          "AverageSellingUnitWeight" : 1.785,
          "description" : [ "Fresh Class A whole chicken without giblets."],
          "UnitQuantity" : "KG",
          "id" : 292276232,
          "ContentsQuantity" : 1.75,
          "department" : "Fresh Meat & Poultry",
          "price" : 3.5,
          "unitprice" : 2.0
        } ],
        "suggestions" : [ ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However I still don't receive the image URL in textbox1, and have no idea as to why. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used `JSON.NET` or `NEWTONSOFT`, I tend to only mess around with JSON a little, I usually just use the 'built in' method.

Your results are in an array which is what your first problem would probably have been. Then your `For Each` looks like it's getting on the right track but not sure `results` are being referenced correctly?

Anyway...

He's a working example that will hopefully help.

I just made a simple WinForm and added a `button`.
I added a reference to: `System.Web.Extensions`

Try code below: (let me know how you got on)

```
Imports System.Web.Script.Serialization

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        'This is just my JSON source I used for testing. (The JSON response you posted)
        Dim raw As String = IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\MEDIA\json_test.json")

        'This should now be the same as your: Dim raw As String = read.ReadToEnd()
        'From here on, try this:

        'Deserialise
        Dim ser As JavaScriptSerializer = New JavaScriptSerializer()
        Dim Tesco As JSON = New JSON
        Tesco = ser.Deserialize(Of JSON)(raw)

        'Loop through results and print each image URL
        For Each r As Result In Tesco.uk.ghs.products.results
            Console.WriteLine("Image URL:" & r.image)
        Next
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Totals
    Public Property all As Integer
    Public Property [new] As Integer
    Public Property offer As Integer
End Class

Public Class Result
    Public Property image As String
    Public Property superDepartment As String
    Public Property tpnb As Integer
    Public Property ContentsMeasureType As String
    Public Property name As String
    Public Property UnitOfSale As Integer
    Public Property description As String()
    Public Property AverageSellingUnitWeight As Double
    Public Property UnitQuantity As String
    Public Property id As Integer
    Public Property ContentsQuantity As Double
    Public Property department As String
    Public Property price As Double
    Public Property unitprice As Double
End Class

Public Class Products
    Public Property input_query As String
    Public Property output_query As String
    Public Property queryPhase As String
    Public Property totals As Totals
    Public Property config As String
    Public Property results As Result()
    Public Property suggestions As Object()
End Class

Public Class Ghs
    Public Property products As Products
End Class

Public Class Uk
    Public Property ghs As Ghs
End Class

Public Class JSON
    Public Property uk As Uk
End Class
```

Comment: Works perfectly! I got so carried away initially that I thought it wasn't possible naturally and that I needed to use JSON.NET. Also my FOR loop was amusingly syntaxed. Thank you so much!